# Why is @GenerateMicroBenchmark missing in JMH and what is its replacement?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, jmh

I tried to create benchmarks with [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and all tutorials i found refer to `@GenerateMicroBenchmark`.

But i cannot find it in jmh-core:1.11.3.

If it was removed, what is its replacement and what is the *idiomatic* way to create benchmarks without that annotation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the documentation here http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

The first example has

```
@Benchmark
public void wellHelloThere() {
    // this method was intentionally left blank.
}
```

It appears the annotation you mention was renamed 2-3 years ago.

Comment: It seems as there are a lot of outdated tutorials out there. The examples are hidden at the end of the page you mentioned

Comment: The tutorials in https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/tree/master/jmh-samples are always good, since they're maintained alongside the project code.